# how to create a calculation along with the dynamically added rows using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form which dynamically adds table rows on a button click. So far everything is working fine but now I need to calculate two fields which are named as `unit` and `rate` 
and the calculation should be something like `unit*rate = amount` and the value of the amount should be shown in my total amount field. I know the simple calculation but I don't know how to do this with dynamically added rows. Can anyone help me out?

**This is my script to add a new row:**

```
                    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
          var currentItem = $('#items').val();
                $('#addnew').click(function() {
                    currentItem++;
                    $('#items').val(currentItem);
                    //var strToAdd = ;
                     $('#data').append('<tr><td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="ord" maxlength="6" name="ord_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="return copy(this.val());"/></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="srno" maxlength="6" name="srno_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth"/></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_' + currentItem + '" id="descrip" cols="70" class="form-input-textarea"></textarea></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="unit" maxlength="6" name="unit_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate"/></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="prevqty" maxlength="6" name="unit_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate"/></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="thisqty" maxlength="6" name="unit_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate"/></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="qty" maxlength="6" name="unit_' + currentItem + '" class="qty form-input-rate"  onkeyup="calculateRow();"/></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="rate" maxlength="6" name="rate_' + currentItem + '" class="rate form-input-rate"  onkeyup="calculateRow();"/></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="amt" maxlength="6" name="amt_' + currentItem + '" class="cal form-input-rate"  onkeyup="calculateRow();"/></td>\n\
                                        </tr>');

                });
            });
   //]]>
     </script>
```

here is my calculation code but its not seem to work when i add a new row

```
function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    $(".cal").each(function () {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#total").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}

function calculateRow() {

    $('.qty, .rate').keyup(function () {
        var cost = 0;
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var qty = parseFloat($row.find('.qty').val());
        var rate = parseFloat($(".rate").val())
        cost = qty * rate;
           //  alert($("#rate").val());

        if (isNaN(cost)) {
            $row.find('.cal').val("0");
        } else {
            $row.find('.cal').val(cost);
        }
        calculateSum();
    })
}
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code. First, your ID attributes on your input elements will be repeated on the page for every row. This is invalid HTML. Every ID on the page should be unique.

Second, you are adding an `onkeyup` event on your unit, rate, and total inputs that calls `calculateRow`, which then re-binds another `keyup` event to the inputs. So every time you press a key, you're binding the function *again and again*. Try this:

```
function calculateRow() {
    var cost = 0;
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var qty = parseFloat($row.find('.qty').val());

    // changed the following line to only look within the current row
    var rate = parseFloat($row.find('.rate').val());

    cost = qty * rate;

    if (isNaN(cost)) {
        $row.find('.cal').val("0");
    } else {
        $row.find('.cal').val(cost);
    }
    calculateSum();
}
```

---

***UPDATE:***

I would also remove the inline `onkeydown` event bindings and move it up above:

```
$('#data').on('keyup', '.qty, .rate, .cal', calculateRow);
```

This binds the event to the `#data` element, and only calls the event listener when an element matching `.qty, .rate, .cal` within `#data` triggers the event. So this works for dynamically added elements as well, as long as you don't remove the `#data` element.

Comment: so will it work ?? i mean the problem is the qty is getting multiplied by the frst rows rate's value

Comment: Did you notice the comment in the code, where I changed one of the lines in your function? I think you were getting the rate from the first row because you weren't searching for the rate just within that row (you weren't using `$row.find()`). So you would have matched ***all*** elements with the class `rate`.

Comment: Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3G3Zy/2/). Notice that I also removed the inline `onkeydown` event binding and did it up above. It seems to be working as expected. If it doesn't work for you, can you try and make your own jsFiddle that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: sir your fiddle is working fine but wen i copy and try to run this on my side it doesn't even add rows too

Comment: When you copy it to your code, you'll need to wrap all the JavaScript in a `$(document).ready(function() { /* JS code here */ });` block (jsFiddle does this automatically). If that still doesn't work, are you getting any errors in your JS console? You may want to update your question with the new code you're using and then I can continue helping.